# Joomla 3.2 Breezingforms build 825 Recaptcha not working

Tags: joomla, recaptcha, breezingforms

I'm having a problem with Recaptcha in forms created with (Joomla 3.2) Breezingforms build 825.  Recaptcha isn't working all it does is display the label.  The core Joomla Recaptcha works fine now I've changed the server values to the new Google values.

I've got Admintools installed but I don't think this is causing a problem.

Firebug Console shows the following.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: RecaptchaState is not defined recaptcha.js:103
B._reset_timer recaptcha.js:103
B.challenge_callback recaptcha.js:92
(anonymous function) recaptcha.js:110
(anonymous function) recaptcha.js:110
```

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should aim your question at the developer of Breezing Forms either by using the forum or contacting them via email

Comment: Done that, I was hoping someone here might have come across the error message above and knows what it means along with a possible solution.

Comment: are you loading 2 version of jQuery on your site? is jQuery being loaded before Mootools? Check the console for these 2 things as it's possible that there is a conflict with some JS libraries

Comment: Hi Lodder, many thanks for your suggestion, I've checked it out and no conflicting JS libraries.

Comment: I've managed to get Captcha to work but still no Recaptcha.  Happy with Captcha so will live with that.  Thanks for your help Lodder, very much appreciated.

Comment: I have to admit, I much prefer Captcha to ReCaptcha. Much more simple and easier to read

Comment: I assume you've set up the recapcha keys?  I use it with admin tools all the time without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you, by any chance, using JCH Optimize? if you are, add the following to JCH Optimize "Exclude JavaScript Files" box and you should be fine:

recaptcha.js"